# sum of overlapping arrays, auto-vectorization, and restrict

Tags: c++, c, optimization, sse, auto-vectorization

Arstechnia recently had an article [Why are some programming languages faster than others](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/05/ask-ars-why-are-some-programming-languages-faster-than-others/).  It compares Fortran and C and mentions summing arrays.  In Fortran it's assumed that arrays don't overlap so that allows further optimization.  In C/C++ pointers to the same type may overlap so this optimization can't be used in general.  However, in C/C++ one can use the `restrict` or `__restrict` keyword to tell the compiler not to assume the pointers overlap.  So I started looking into this in regards to auto-vectorization.

The following code vectorizes in GCC and MSVC

```
void dot_int(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

I tested this with and without overlapping arrays and it gets the correct result. However, the way I would vectorize this loop manually with SSE does not handle overlapping arrays.

```
int i=0;    
for(; i<n-3; i+=4) {
    __m128i a4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&a[i]);
    __m128i b4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&b[i]);
    __m128i c4 = _mm_add_epi32(a4,b4);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)c, c4);
}
for(; i<n; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Next I tried using `__restrict`.  I assumed that since the compiler could assume the arrays don't overlap it would not handle overlapping arrays but both GCC and MSVC still get the correct result for overlapping arrays even with `__restrict`.

```
void dot_int_restrict(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

**Why does the auto-vectorized code with and without `__restrict` get the correct result for overlapping arrays?**.

Here is the full code I used to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
void dot_int(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d ", c[i]); printf("\n"); 
}

void dot_int_restrict(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d ", c[i]); printf("\n"); 
}

void dot_int_SSE(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) {
    int i=0;    
    for(; i<n-3; i+=4) {
        __m128i a4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&a[i]);
        __m128i b4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&b[i]);
        __m128i c4 = _mm_add_epi32(a4,b4);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)c, c4);
    }
    for(; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d ", c[i]); printf("\n"); 
}

int main() {
    const int n = 100;
    int a[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int b1[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int b2[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int b3[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    int c[8];
    int *c1 = &b1[1];
    int *c2 = &b2[1];
    int *c3 = &b3[1];

    dot_int(a,b1,c, 8);
    dot_int_SSE(a,b1,c,8);

    dot_int(a,b1,c1, 8);
    dot_int_restrict(a,b2,c2,8);
    dot_int_SSE(a,b3,c3,8);

}
```

The output (from MSVC)

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 //no overlap default
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 //no overlap with manual SSE vector code
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 //overlap default
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 //overlap with restrict
3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 //manual SSE vector code
```

Edit:

Here is another inserting version which produces much simpler code

```
void dot_int(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c, int n) {
    a = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (a, 16);
    b = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (b, 16);
    c = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (c, 16);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test case doesn't exercise the case where aliased input data would be problematic. You need to a case where input and output pointers are aliased to the same array and where the load-store order matters.

Comment: @PaulR, I thought that's what I did.  I added the output to the end of my question.  The output `c` array overlaps the input `b` array.  The reason the manual SSE code fails is because the load-store order matters.

Comment: OK - sorry - perhaps I mis-read your code.

Comment: How do you know compiler is vectorizing the code? What vectorized code is the compiler generating for this function?

Comment: @Apriori, both compilers, GCC and MSVC, report that they vectorize the loop.  That's how I know.  The assembly was much longer than I expected but a first look indicates that the compiler produces a vectorized and non-vectorized version and then decides which path to take based on if the arrays overlap (memory address and range).  But that's still a guess, I'll have more time to check this tomorrow.

Comment: @Z boson: that makes sense. I'll be interested in what you find out. Perf numbers might also expose the level of optimization that is being performed on the code. I've spent some time using the __restrict keyword myself and never been able to see any difference, at least on x86/x64; I'd be curious to hear examples where it has made a positive difference in the generated assembly. My understanding is it's more important on PowerPC where load hit sores are a bigger problem. Of course the optimization we'd like to see here is completely different.

Answer (score 5):

I don't get what the problem is. Testing on Linux/64 bit, GCC 4.6, -O3, -mtune=native, -msse4.1 (i.e. a very old compiler/system), this code

```
void dot_int(int *a, int *b, int *c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

compiles to this inner loop:

```
.L4:
    movdqu  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm1
    addl    $1, %r8d
    movdqu  (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movdqu  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpl    %r8d, %r10d
    ja      .L4
    cmpl    %r9d, %ecx
    je      .L1
```

While this code

```
void dot_int_restrict(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

compiles to this:

```
.L15:
    movdqu  (%rbx,%rax), %xmm0
    addl    $1, %r8d
    paddd   0(%rbp,%rax), %xmm0
    movdqu  %xmm0, (%r11,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpl    %r10d, %r8d
    jb      .L15
    addl    %r12d, %r9d
    cmpl    %r12d, %r13d
    je      .L10
```

As you can clearly see there's one less load. I guess it correclty estimated that there's no need to explicitely load memory before performing the sum, as the result won't overwrite anythng.

There's also room for way more optimizations -- GCC doesn't know that the parameters are f.i. 128 bit aligned, hence it must generate a huge preamble to check that there are no alignment issues (YMMV), and a postable to deal with extra unaligned parts (or less wide than 128 bits). This actually happens with both versions above. This is the complete code generated for `dot_int`:

```
dot_int:
.LFB626:
        .cfi_startproc
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 3, -16
        jle     .L1
        leaq    16(%rdx), %r11
        movl    %ecx, %r10d
        shrl    $2, %r10d
        leal    0(,%r10,4), %r9d
        testl   %r9d, %r9d
        je      .L6
        leaq    16(%rdi), %rax
        cmpl    $6, %ecx
        seta    %r8b
        cmpq    %rax, %rdx
        seta    %al
        cmpq    %r11, %rdi
        seta    %bl
        orl     %ebx, %eax
        andl    %eax, %r8d
        leaq    16(%rsi), %rax
        cmpq    %rax, %rdx
        seta    %al
        cmpq    %r11, %rsi
        seta    %r11b
        orl     %r11d, %eax
        testb   %al, %r8b
        je      .L6
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        movdqu  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm1
        addl    $1, %r8d
        movdqu  (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
        paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movdqu  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
        addq    $16, %rax
        cmpl    %r8d, %r10d
        ja      .L4
        cmpl    %r9d, %ecx
        je      .L1
.L3:
        movslq  %r9d, %r8
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        salq    $2, %r8
        addq    %r8, %rdx
        addq    %r8, %rdi
        addq    %r8, %rsi
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L5:
        movl    (%rdi,%rax,4), %r8d
        addl    (%rsi,%rax,4), %r8d
        movl    %r8d, (%rdx,%rax,4)
        addq    $1, %rax
        leal    (%r9,%rax), %r8d
        cmpl    %r8d, %ecx
        jg      .L5
.L1:
        popq    %rbx
        .cfi_remember_state
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
.L6:
        .cfi_restore_state
        xorl    %r9d, %r9d
        jmp     .L3
        .cfi_endproc
```

Now in your case the ints effectively *not* aligned (as they're on the stack), but if you can make them aligned and tell GCC so, then you can improve code generation:

```
typedef int intvec __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

void dot_int_restrict_alig(intvec * restrict a, 
                           intvec * restrict b, 
                           intvec * restrict c, 
                           unsigned int n) {
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

This generates this code, with no preamble:

```
dot_int_restrict_alig:
.LFB628:
        .cfi_startproc
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        je      .L23
        subl    $1, %ecx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $1, %rcx
        salq    $4, %rcx
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L25:
        movdqa  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
        paddd   (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
        movdqa  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
        addq    $16, %rax
        cmpq    %rcx, %rax
        jne     .L25
.L23:
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Note the usage of the aligned 128 bit load instructions (`movdqa`, *a* as aligned, vs `movdqu`, unaligned).

Comment: I think there is a non-vectorized version of the code as well.  At least that's what it appears at http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  My guess is that the compiler makes both version and then when it enters the function it decides if the arrays overlap and then choses the vectorized or non vectorized version.  In any case, I'll check out your answer more carefully tomorrow.

Comment: Your function `dot_int_restrict_alig` produces almost the identical code that my manual SSE function does except it uses aligned loads/stores and it core dumps on the overlapping arrays.  The assembly you posted is incapable of handling the overlapping arrays.  There must be more code (which you did not post) which handles the cases for overlapping arrays.

Comment: Do you mean, more code generated from `dot_int_restrict_alig`? No, that's the entire generated function. It doesn't handle overlapping arrays at all -- arguments are `restrict`.

Comment: No, I mean from the other functions.

Comment: Yes, other functions had the huge preamble I posted around the vectorized loop. They also had as small code after the vectorized loop them I didn't paste. I'll modify my post and add it.

Comment: What I mean is the assembly code you posted for `dot_int` cannot handle overlapping arrays so there must be some other code either in the preamble or after which handles it.  I think it's checking the arrays for overlap and choosing to use the vectorized version or not (see my answer).  If you can show this in the assembly I'll give you the accepted answer (I already gave you +1).  Right now though your answer does not explain how the assembly gets the overlap correct for `dot_int`.

Comment: I see you added the full code.  If you look at the code.  It either does .L4 and then .L1 or it jumps to .L6 to .L3 to .L5 to .L1.  It's the .L5 part which is the non-vectorized part I believe.  So the preamble is doing more than checking alignment it's all checking for overlap I think.

Comment: In fact if you compile without vectorization (just change -O3 to -O2) the code is just the .L5 part of your code so that's clearly the non-vectorized part.

Comment: I updated the end of my answer using `__builtin_assume_aligned` which gives a much smaller preamble.

Answer (score 2):

If you use "restrict" with overlapping arrays, you will get undefined behaviour. That's what you get in the "overlap restrict" case. Undefined behaviour means **anything** can happen. And it did. Just by coincidence, the behaviour was the same as without "restrict". Absolutely correct. It falls straight under the definition of "anything can happen". Nothing to complain about.

Comment: I don't agree.  When the arrays don't overlap the most optimal solution is the one I did manually.  If the compiler assumed the arrays don't overlap it should have produced that which CANNOT get the same result.  I think it's much more likely that the compiler ignored the restrict  keyword.

Comment: Another point is why is this function vectorized at all even without restrict?  How do you vectorized this efficiently when you can't assume the arrays don't overlap?  I don't see how this can be done efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what is going on now. It turns out that MSVC and GCC give different results with `__restrict`.  MSVC gets the correct answer with the overlap and GCC does not.  I think it's fair to conclude then that MSVC is ignoring the `__restrict` keyword and GCC is using it to optimize further.

The output from GCC

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 //no overlap default
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 //no overlap with manual SSE vector code
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 //overlap without __restrict
2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 //overlap with __restrict
3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 //manual SSE vector code
```

We can produce a purely vectorized function which gives almost as many assembly lines as C doing (all the code is generated with `-O3` in GCC 4.9.0) this:

```
void dot_int(int * __ restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) {
    a = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (a, 16);
    b = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (b, 16);
    c = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (c, 16);
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

Produces

```
dot_int(int*, int*, int*):
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L2:
    movdqa  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
    paddd   (%rsi,%rax), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpq    $4096, %rax
    jne .L2
    rep ret
```

However, if we remove the `__restrict on a` which allows a to overlap with c I have determined by looking at the assembly that

```
void dot_int(int * a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) {
        a = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (a, 16);
        b = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (b, 16);
        c = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (c, 16);
        for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
    }
```

Is identical to

```
__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))
inline void dot_SSE(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) {
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i+=4) {    
        __m128i a4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&a[i]);
        __m128i b4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&a[i]);
        __m128i c4 = _mm_add_epi32(a4,b4);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&c[i],c4);
    }
}
__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))
void dot_int(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) {
    a = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (a, 16);
    b = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (b, 16);
    c = (int*)__builtin_assume_aligned (c, 16);
    int pass = 1;
    if((c+4)<a || (a+4)<c) pass = 0;
    if(pass) {
        for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }   
    }
    else {
        dot_SSE(a,b,c);
    }
}
```

**In other words if the a and c pointers are within 16 bytes of each other (|a-c|<4) then the code branches to a non-vectorized form.**  This confirms my guess that the auto-vectorized code includes both a vectorized and non-vectorized version to handle overlap.

On the overlapping arrays this gets the correct result: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: The first interval `i1 = a-b` I don't think is necessary because it's okay if the inputs overlap.