# Tell C++ that pointer data is 16 byte aligned

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, memory-alignment

I wrote some code with static arrays and it vectorizes just fine.

```
float data[1024] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

I would like to make the arrays dynamically allocated. I tried doing something like this:

```
float *data = (float*) aligned_alloc(16, size*sizeof(float));
```

But the compiler (GCC 4.9.2), no longer can vectorize the code. I assume this is because it doesn't know the pointer data is 16 byte aligned. I am getting messages like:

```
note: Unknown alignment for access: *_43
```

I have tried adding this line before the data is used, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
data = (float*) __builtin_assume_aligned(data, 16);
```

Using a different variable and `restrict` did not help:

```
float* __restrict__ align_data = (float*) __builtin_assume_aligned(data,16);
```

***Example:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 1024
#define DYNAMIC 0
#define A16 __attribute__((aligned(16)))
#define DA16 (float*) aligned_alloc(16, size*sizeof(float))

class Test{
public:
    int size;
#if DYNAMIC
    float *pos;
    float *vel;
    float *alpha;
    float *k_inv;
    float *osc_sin;
    float *osc_cos;
    float *dosc1;
    float *dosc2;
#else
    float pos[SIZE] A16;
    float vel[SIZE] A16;
    float alpha[SIZE] A16;
    float k_inv[SIZE] A16;
    float osc_sin[SIZE] A16;
    float osc_cos[SIZE] A16;
    float dosc1[SIZE] A16;
    float dosc2[SIZE] A16;
#endif
    Test(int arr_size){
        size = arr_size;
#if DYNAMIC
        pos = DA16;
        vel = DA16;
        alpha = DA16;
        k_inv = DA16;
        osc_sin = DA16;
        osc_cos = DA16;
        dosc1 = DA16;
        dosc2 = DA16;
#endif
    }
    void compute(){
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            float lambda = .67891*k_inv[i],
                omega = (.89 - 2*alpha[i]*lambda)*k_inv[i],
                diff2 = pos[i] - omega,
                diff1 = vel[i] - lambda + alpha[i]*diff2;
            pos[i] = osc_sin[i]*diff1 + osc_cos[i]*diff2 + lambda*.008 + omega;
            vel[i] = dosc1[i]*diff1 - dosc2[i]*diff2 + lambda;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Test t(SIZE);
    t.compute();
    std::cout << t.pos[10] << std::endl;
    std::cout << t.vel[10] << std::endl;
}
```

Here is how I am compiling:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -fopt-info-optimized
```

When `DYNAMIC` is set to `0`, it outputs:

```
test.cpp:46:4: note: loop vectorized
```

but when it is set to `1` it outputs nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using new?

Comment: I haven't yet; I didn't think it could guarantee 16 byte alignment.

Comment: `new float[size]` doesn't give vectorized code and gcc still has `Unknown alignment...` errors

Comment: @Azmisov - what code are you using that is expected to be vectorized? Also, did you try assigning it to a different variable? i.e. `float *alignedData = __builtin_assume_aligned(data, 16);`

Comment: Btw, I'm saying that just based on this here: http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/

Comment: @Azmisov How about the std::align in the post mentioned above?

Comment: @EboMike That doesn't seem to help. The code is a little long, but I can try and throw together a minimized version, if I can.

Comment: @JTrana Apparently gcc doesn't have `std::align` implemented yet, as I can't get it to compile.

Comment: Maybe I should upgrade to GCC 5.1

Comment: You may try platform-specific allocation `http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign`

Comment: @Azmisov can you post the loop you are using this? According to the link EboMike said, it is bad to make two loops while trying to do a vectorization.

Comment: @Azmisov also try adding the keyword `restrict` to your pointers. It might help as well.

Comment: I think you're on the track, you need to put the `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` on the pointer type, just like it was on the array. Though I would use a typedef or even a struct for this.

Comment: Can you write the additions you make to the question in the question? It is anoying the gather this from comments.

Comment: `__builtin_assume_aligned` [has worked for me in the past along with restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651055/sum-of-overlapping-arrays-auto-vectorization-and-restrict). Post a minimal working example so we can see what is happening.

Comment: It's strange that the compiler would no longer vectorize the code because of alignment. Even if it's not aligned it would still vectorize but put in additional code to correct for the misalignment.  Maybe it has something to do with one being a pointer and one being an array (the compiler knows the array has 1024 elements but not the size of the memory the pointer references).

Comment: I usually use `_mm_malloc` because it works for GCC, ICC, MSVC, and MinGW.

Comment: I added an example. I haven't tried some of the suggestions yet, so I'll keep fiddling with it.

Comment: vectorizing `atan2` is hard. In the static version, `phase` is eliminated since it is never read.

Comment: @MarcGlisse You're right; originally, when I was compiling, it was optimizing it to some SSE optimized `atan2`. I updated the example and removed the `sqrt`/`atan2` calculations. But, It still isn't vectorizing.

Comment: Try renaming `main` to `some_function` and the code now vectorizes ;-) The reason is that `main` is only ever called once, so it is marked as "cold" by the compiler, which disables some optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler isn't vectorizing the loop because it can't determine that the dynamically allocated pointers don't alias each other. A simple way to allow your sample code to be vectorized is to pass the `--param vect-max-version-for-alias-checks=1000` option. This will allow the compiler to emit all the checks necessary to see if the pointers are actually aliased.

Another simple solution to allow your you example code to be vectorized is to rename `main`, as suggested by Marc Glisse in his comment. Functions named `main` apparently have certain optimizations disabled. Named something else, GCC 4.9.2 can track the use of `this->foo` (and the other pointer members) in `compute` back to their allocations in `Test()`.

However, I assume something other than your class being used in a function named `main` prevented your code being vectorized in your real code. A more general solution that allows your code to vectorized without aliasing or alignment checks is to use the `restrict` keyword and the `aligned` attribute. Something like this:

```
typedef float __attribute__((aligned(16))) float_a16;

__attribute__((noinline))
static void _compute(float_a16 * __restrict__ pos,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ vel,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ alpha,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ k_inv,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ osc_sin,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ osc_cos,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ dosc1,
         float_a16 * __restrict__ dosc2,
         int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        float lambda = .67891*k_inv[i],
            omega = (.89 - 2*alpha[i]*lambda)*k_inv[i],
            diff2 = pos[i] - omega,
            diff1 = vel[i] - lambda + alpha[i]*diff2;
        pos[i] = osc_sin[i]*diff1 + osc_cos[i]*diff2 + lambda*.008 + omega;
        vel[i] = dosc1[i]*diff1 - dosc2[i]*diff2 + lambda;
    }
}

void compute() {
    _compute(pos, vel, alpha, k_inv, osc_sin, osc_cos, dosc1, dosc2,
         size);
}
```

The `noinline` attribute is critical, otherwise inlining can cause the pointers to lose their restrictedness and alignedness. The compiler seems to ignore the `restrict` keyword in contexts other than function parameters.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Is there any way to use the `restrict` keyword without passing everything into a separate function? It seems cumbersome to have to do that for every sse function.

Comment: @Azmisov Unfortunately, this is the only way I found that worked.

Comment: I believe the handling of restrict with inlining was improved in gcc-5 and the functions aligned_alloc and posix_memalign were marked like malloc as returning disjoint memory regions, but that compiler simply crashes on this testcase :-(

Comment: @MarcGlisse, do you have a reference which discusses malloc return disjoint memory regions. That's interesting.

Comment: @Azmisov, another option is to explicitly vectorize your code. Then you don't have to worry about restrict. I use the [Vector Class Library](http://agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) and am interested in [Yeppp!](http://www.yeppp.info/index.html) as well.

Comment: @Zboson If a function is marked with `__attribute__((malloc)))` then GCC can assume that the pointer returned doesn't refer to the storage of any other object. (It also can assume the memory is uninitialized.)  In the case of malloc then the program would have to invoke undefined behaviour for that not be true. GCC could take advantage here of this if it can connect the use of `this->pos` in `compute` (and `vel`, `alpha`, etc...)  to the allocation of `this->pos` in `Test()` without `this` escaping in between. You can get this to work in the example by renaming main.

Comment: The attribute is documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bmalloc_007d-function-attribute-3096